# How can I connect a receptacle to a two wire extension cord?

Tags: electrical

How do I hook up a wall outlet to a 2 wire extension cord? My cord broke and I want to put a regular 110 outlet on it.

Answer (score 4):

If your extension cord breaks, they make replacement ends for them. I'd only do this with a high priced outdoor extension cord, the cheaper cords should just be replaced completely.

[image: replacement end]

[image: replacement plug]

Answer (score 3):

## Supplies:

- Metal single gang device box
  [image]
- A cable clamp.
  [image]
- A Ground-Fault Circuit Interrupting (GFCI) receptacle.
  [image]
- A cover plate.
  [image]

***NOTE:** If the cord is going to be used outdoors; or in other damp or wet locations, use a weatherproof box, clamp, and in-use cover.*

## Procedure:

1. Punch out one of the knockouts in the electrical box.
2. Install the cable clamp in the hole you just created.
3. Strip about 6" of the outer outer jacket from the cable.
4. Fit the cord through the clamp so that about 1/2" of the outer jacket is inside the box, then tighten down the clamp.
5. Strip about 3/4" of insulation from the end of each wire.
6. Connect the ungrounded (hot) conductor of the cord, to the brass colored screw labeled LINE on the receptacle.
7. Connect the grounded (neutral) conductor of the cord, to the silver colored screw labeled LINE on the receptacle.
8. Install the receptacle in the box.
9. Install the cover plate.

## Testing and use

1. Plug the extension cord into a working receptacle.
2. Press the RESET button on the GFCI receptacle.
3. Use a receptacle tester or lamp to verify the GFCI receptacle is working.
4. Press the TEST button on the GFCI receptacle.
5. Verify the GFCI receptacle has lost power.
6. Press the RESET button again, and verify power is restored.
7. Use the cord.

***NOTE:** This procedure should be followed each time the cord is used, to insure the GFCI receptacle is functioning properly.*

---

Or, simply buy a new cord end for a dollar or two.

[image]

Comment: Oh, sure, steal my superior answer with a late edit. :oP

Comment: This would be a betterer tutorial on making a DIY GFCI extension cord if you made some recommendations regarding cordage and strain relief.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP already has a cord, since they asked how to add a receptacle to their broken cord.  As for strain relief, the clamp should handle that.

Comment: Isn't that clamp more intended for type NM cable, for fixed in wall use.  I would question its use as a flexible cable anchor point.  Would the 2014 NEC approve this assembly? Isn't the OP talking about "zip" cord?

Comment: One tiny additional point:  most cover plates are designed to go over an in-wall box.  An on-wall or free box needs a special plate. (if a free box is even allowed...)

Comment: @HerrBag You'd have to check with UL not NEC. But since I don't expect the OP is going to file for UL testing, it's a moot point.  The cable clamp I've shown in the post will hold for normal usage, if you're mountain climbing or slacklining with the cord you'll likely run into some problems.